# WKNavigationDelegate using Objective-C Bridge (JXA)

Tags: javascript-automation

I'm trying to create a WKNavigationDelegate for a WKWebView but have been unable to call the `decisionHandler`. Does anyone have any idea how to do this?

```js
ObjC.registerSubclass({
    name: "test",
    methods: {
        "webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:decisionHandler:": {
             types: ["void", ["id", "id", "id"]],
             implementation: function(wv, navigationAction, decisionHandler) {
                 decisionHandler($.WKNavigationActionPolicyAllow);
                 return;
            }
        }
    }
});
var delegate = $['test'].alloc.init;
webView.navigationDelegate = delegate;
```

The code works up to the point where it prevents the navigation action but the `decisionHandler` is not called!

In the console I get the log:

```js
Completion handler passed to -[test webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:decisionHandler:] was not called
```

Changing the type from "id" to "block" or "function" doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I'd add a comment but confusing SO rules prohibit newbs from *not* answering (?!). Does adding `protocols: ['WKNavigationDelegate']` to the registration help?
Your method is being called, and $.WKNavigationActionPolicyAllow shows as being == 1, but maybe the protocol will assist type inference by JSC.